# Java program doesn't show the desired output

Tags: java, bluej

I am new to Java programming. I've been trying to write some code in Java but the desired output (or the output which must come) is never received. (Refer the code from here)For example, if I enter quantity 4 for the category 'w' then according to me it must give the output as  $2940 but instead of the output '$2940' it displays the output as $38480. Please help and thanks in advance...

```
case 'A':
case 'a':
    System.out.println("You selected NOS Tank.");
    int price;
    double quantity;
    double variant=0; 
    System.out.println("Select the variant: ");                                                    
    System.out.println("Enter 'D' without apostrophe for dry or 'W' for wet");
    variant=xss.next().charAt(0);                                                                  
    if (variant=='D' || variant=='d'){                
        System.out.println("The price of dry nitrous oxide system is: $600");                
    } else if (variant=='w' || variant=='W'){                
        System.out.println("The price of wet nitrous oxide is: $740");               
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input.");                                                      
        System.out.println("Exiting......");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Enter the quantity: ");
    quantity=xss.next().charAt(0);
    if (variant=='D' || variant=='d') {
        System.out.println("The amount payable is: $"+(quantity*600));
    } else if (variant=='w' || variant=='W') {
        System.out.println("The amount payable is: $"+(quantity*740));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid input.");                                                      
        System.out.println("Exiting......");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: `double variant=0;`??? Why hold a char in a double variable? This should be a char variable so as not to lose precision

Comment: How is xss initialized? Try printing the quantity along with the amount. Then you can confirm if the correct quantity is being picked up.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No luck dude. Still it is showing some weird output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing

```
quantity=xss.next().charAt(0);
```

Now character at this location is 4. But when you store it in `int`, it will take it's ASCII value which is 52.
May be try

```
quantity=Integer.parseInt(xss.next().charAt(0)+"");
```

Or

```
quantity=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(xss.next().charAt(0)));
```

Comment: Thanks man. Worked really well for me.